# Recognizing an action only when I tap the SKSpriteNode?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have the following segment of code in which I want a tap to cause the ball to move in my screen.

```
   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        moveBallUp()
        moveBallLeft()
        moveBallRight()
    }

    func moveBallUp() -> Void {
        ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, impulseFactor))
    }

    func moveBallLeft() -> Void {
        var random = -1 * CGFloat(Float(arc4random()))
        ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(random % impulseFactor, 0))
    }

    func moveBallRight() -> Void {
        var random = CGFloat(Float(arc4random()))
        ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(random % impulseFactor, 0))
    }
```

How do I make it such that only taps on the SKSpriteNode variable "ball" will cause the ball to move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set ball's name (`ballNode.name = "ball"`) and access it like this:

**touchesBegan:**

```
 let location = (touch as UITouch).locationInNode(self)

 if let ball = self.nodeAtPoint(location) 
     if ball.name == "ball" {
        //move the ball
     }
 }
```

Another way would be using subclassing SKSpriteNode (and implementing touchesBegan method) like this:

```
class Ball : SKSpriteNode
{
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
       //do your stuff here
    }
}
```

If you are subclassing SKSpriteNode you have to set `userInteractionEnabled = true.` you can do this in ball's init method or after you create Ball object.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I was initially trying to do it using the method before Swift 1.2, but this worked for me. Thank you so much!